# Session Variable Scope Not Working

Tags: php, session, variables, session-variables, captcha

I am having problems trying to set session variables from another page.

I have a captcha class (CaptchaSecurityImages.php By Simon Jarvis) and though the code might be a bit dated (last updated 07/02/07), it works on my local machine and not on my GoDaddy server.

This is the function called to generate a captcha code and to set a session variable. I modified the code a little bit to allow custom session variables names to be set ($sessionvar)

```
<?php
session_start();
class CaptchaSecurityImages {

var $font = 'monofont.ttf';

function generateCode($characters) {
    /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
    $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
    $code = '';
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $characters) { 
        $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
        $i++;
    }
    return $code;
}

function CaptchaSecurityImages($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6',$sessionvar='security_code') {
    $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
    $_SESSION[$sessionvar] = $code; // doesnt actually set anything

    /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
    $font_size = $height * 0.75;
    $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
    /* set the colours */
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
    $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 180);
    /* generate random dots in background */
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
    }
    /* generate random lines in background */
    for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
        imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
    }
    /* create textbox and add text */
    $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
    $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
    $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
    /* output captcha image to browser */
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
}
$width = isset($_GET['width']) ? $_GET['width'] : '120';
$height = isset($_GET['height']) ? $_GET['height'] : '40';
$characters = isset($_GET['characters']) && $_GET['characters'] > 1 ? $_GET['characters'] : '6';
$sessionvar = isset($_GET['session']) ? $_GET['session'] : 'security_code';
$captcha = new CaptchaSecurityImages($width,$height,$characters, $sessionvar);

// if the next line was enabled, the session would be set
//echo $_SESSION[$sessionvar];

?>
```

The page calling this looks something like this:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); } 
echo $_SESSION['paysecuritycode']; // should output something when the page is refreshed
?>
<html>
...
<body>
<img src='captchacode.inc.php?width=100&amp;height=40&amp;characters=5&amp;session=paysecuritycode'; />
</body>
</html>
```

So when echo $_SESSION['paysecuritycode'] is called there's no display? Whats missing? Is it possible to set variables from a function instead a class, surely?

Perhaps is there any server configuration issues that I should double check? Though creating session variables do work when inside .php code - so not sure why this is?

Are there any session/PHP requirements I need to be aware of to make this work??

Comment: Where are you calling the function?  Unless you're changing the default value you have the incorrect key in your `$_SESSION`

Comment: `session_start()` should go at the top of your script, before any HTML is sent to the client

Comment: Guess this calls the function ... <img src='captchacode.inc.php?...

Comment: Like @Phil said, make sure you have a valid session by calling `session_start()` at the top of your script.

Comment: djot is right, the function is called when calling the captchacode.inc.php page. this file has session_start() at the top of the page as well as the top of the HTML file (sorry wrote it off the top of my head). is it possible to set a session variable from within a class? or is there something special that needs to be done?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found following solution (don't like the idea to load the complete framework, but it works). Maybe someone else finds this useful:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

---

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('security_code', $code);
```

Replace `session_start();` with the first part of the code I posted and `$_SESSION['captcha_word'] = $code;` with the last two lines.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are setting and reading different session variables. You are setting `$_SESSION[$sessionvar] = $code;`, but trying to read `$_SESSION['paysecuritycode']`.
`$_SESSION['paysecuritycode']` is not empty only when `$sessionvar` is set to `'paysecuritycode'`, but by default it is set to `'security_code'`.

Besides, `if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }` is useless in the first script as it will raise warning if the session is not started yet (headers already sent by `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`).

Comment: just added the entire code for the captcha class. you will see there is a $_GET['session'] which should detect from the img url and set the session variable name that is passed in? even if it is supposed to default to security_code, there doesnt seem to be any session variable being created from inside the class